# Unable to build php 5.6 or 8, 7.3 builds successfully

Tags: php, directadmin

We have a server where we have 3 php versions installed

5.6, 7.3 and 8.0

All running as FPM. In an attempt to get `MSSQL` extensions working all versions stopped running. The recommendation was to rebuild from custombuild.

7.3 re-built with no issues and (despite `mssql` module still not being present) is now working. but 5.6 and 8.0 returning the following:

```
[root@.. custombuild]# ./build php_expert 8.0 php-fpm
./build: line 13188: ldconfig: command not found
Found /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/php-8.0.1.tar.gz
Extracting ...
Done.
Configuring php-8.0.1...
Patching php-fpm to not fail on startup if User quota maxed out on socket chown
patching file sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_unix.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 242 (offset 7 lines).
Done Configuration.
Can't open Makefile: No such file or directory.
Trying to make php...
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
[root@.. custombuild]#
```

** Update **

So adding sbin to the path has now removed the error abuilt ldconfig command not found but everything else is still the same.

```
[root@... custombuild]# export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
[root@... custombuild]# ./build php_expert 8.0 php-fpm
Found /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/php-8.0.1.tar.gz
Extracting ...
Done.
Configuring php-8.0.1...
Patching php-fpm to not fail on startup if User quota maxed out on socket chown
patching file sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_unix.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 242 (offset 7 lines).
Done Configuration.
Can't open Makefile: No such file or directory.
Trying to make php...
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
[root@... custombuild]#
```

Comment: Is there a makefile in the directory?

Comment: @ThomasSablik sadly I dont know which folder it is refering to, all other php versions build OK

Comment: You should probably ask in the DirectAdmin forum

Comment: Enter `./build  rewrite_confs` command, The problem may be solved